# How can I be sure a script is run in a new fresh session, aka how do I restart Julia at the very beginning of the script?

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I want to be sure a script is run by the user in a fresh Julia session, so I would like to put something at the beginning to restart Julia rather than writing "Hey guy, run this script in a fresh Julia session".

The `run('$(Base.julia_cmd())')` trick works on the REPL but not on VSCode.

Performances are not an issue here.

EDIT:

A bit of context. I am producing some scripts for a course and I want the students to run each script independently, without trash from the previous scripts. I can instruct the students to run the script on a new session, but it would be nice to have something at the top of the script that when they run that line they have a new session if they didn't properly read the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `Distributed` functionality. It just spawns a new fresh session without loaded libraries nor variables:

```
using Distributed
pids  = addprocs(1)
fetch(@spawnat pids[1] include("myscript.jl"))
```

#### EDIT

This simply works for me in VSCode:

```
run(`$(Base.julia_cmd()) myscript.jl`)
```

could it be that you are just using `'` instead of  `  ?

[image]

#### EDIT 2

On Windows you might also like:

```
run(`cmd /c start  $(Base.julia_cmd()) --banner=no -i myscript.jl`)
```

This launches a fresh new interactive Julia session in a detached console window

Comment: Thank you, but the script needs to be run interactively. I added a bit of context to the question.

Comment: Thanks again, no the quote was correct, I couldn't use them here in Markdown. The problem of this approach is that it runs the whole script then, while I want the students to run each command of the script interactively and play with them

Comment: Would code cells work for you (they can be built using `# %%` syntax). However they will all have the same Julia terminal. When running VS Code there is `VSCodeServer` Julia package available but I have not used it and it seems to be quite undocumented.